# As ProgressDialog is deprecated now, how to set message through progressBar?

Tags: android

I have to set a message and title in `onPreExcecute()` but am not able to do it. `ProgressDialog` had the `setMessage()` method, but `ProgressBar` does not.

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {


progressBar.



    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i just want to show loading message in preexcute method through progressBar

Answer (score 0):

Use [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) to show progress and TextView to show message:

```
<ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own ProgressBar and put a Textview next to it. A library from https://github.com/Q115/DelayedProgressDialog will do the trick.

Usage:

```
DelayedProgressDialog progressDialog = new DelayedProgressDialog();
progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlertDialog by overriding onCreateDialog after extending DialogFragment. You should design an xml that contains a ProgressBar and a TextView(for the message). Then call the setView() method of the AlertDialog on the xml like below.

Your layout in xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="loading..."
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your DialogFragment Class

```
 public class Dialog extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
                                         AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
//use layoutinflater to inflate xml
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_containing_progressbar,null));
            return builder.create();
        }
    }
```

you can now call .show on an instance of the DialogFragment Class

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but better late than never...
I had the same problem so I created a custom ProgressBar.

First you make the class for the view:

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends RelativeLayout {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView textView;

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_progress_bar, this);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarCustom);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.pbTV);

        init(attrs);

    private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomProgressBar);
            String textAttrib = ta
                    .getString(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_text);
            textView.setText(textAttrib);
            ta.recycle();
        }
    }

    public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textView.getText().toString();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    public void setText(int resid) {
        textView.setText(resid);
    }

}
```

Then, in order to be able to set this class attributes from the layout, we need to make it styleable. So you need to create an xml file called "attrs.xml" within the directory "values".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomProgressBar">
        <attr name="text" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Now we create the layout for our custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarCustom"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pbTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, just use it wherever you want:

```
<com.example.mypackage.CustomProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:text="Loading..."
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
```

And that's it :)